# Socialengine url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, socialengine

I want to let users access their pages by typing the url http://www.mysite.com/username

So to redirect http://www.mysite.com/username TO http://www.mysite.com/profile/username

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On



  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]


  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]



  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]



  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]



   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_-]+)$ /profile/$1 [R] 


</IfModule>
```

Why wont this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your rule before the other rules. You can start this way.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_-]+)$ /profile/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just note of caution that you might run into an issue of a user has the same name as module you already have. For instance if someone named themselves group (for some reason or another) and you have the groups plugin installed and enabled.